# Render a stripped background on VictoryChart

Tags: reactjs, react-native, charts, victory-charts, victory-native

I am using Victory on React Native to render a Line chart. I want to render a stripped background like this one that i made on Recharts (React JS)

[chart generated by Recharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezhHh.png)

I added this colors using `ReferenceArea`, and I was not able to do that on Victory, I only can fill the background with just one color.

If someone know how to add this background, or knows any other native library that can do that, I would be extremely thankful :)

I tried to use some linear gradients and add other charts behind the line to render a custom background with more than one color, but I was not able to do that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The ```<VictoryChart>``` component accepts a backgroundComponent, where you can pass a custom background, like a striped SVG. See this ReactJS example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tatkpg

Comment: @ViktorG I tried to do that (just like  your example) using the `react-native-svg` lib but it is not working. It is rendering a white screen and I can not even see my chart :(

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that shows what you tried.

Comment: @EidsonSá Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara I was not :( I had to change the library to use react-native-responsive-linechart so I was able to do that